# D3 tree drawing with long labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to print some trees, where the node labels are sentences up to around two hundred characters. Is there a way to specify a maximum width for the labels and have longer labels wrap onto multiple lines?

In other words, the labels attached to the nodes in the following picture:

https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#tree

can be up to around two hundred characters long.

ps. Maybe it does so automatically, but I haven't written the code yet in case using this component of D3 is a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the SVG specification doesn't allow for "word wrapping" to happen. The best you can do is write your own function that will wrap the text into multiple `<tspan></tspan>` tags. Here is an example that you can follow:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321